# EF 6 : Can't generated the query I want, Should Native SQL be used?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have the following two entities with many-to-many mappings:

```
ConferenceRoom {ID, Name, IsAccessibleGlobally}  <--- Many-To-Many ---> Department {ID, Name}
```

- Any department has many conference rooms accessible for the department's employees.
- A conference room might be accessible from multiple departments' employees since a department might have sub-departments. i.e. Any department has also access to its sub-departments' conference rooms.
- A conference room might also be accessible globaly in which case the flag IsAccessibleGlobally is set to true and no records mapping it to a particular department would exist in the table resulting from the many-to-many relation.

Knowing that the the table resulting from the many-to-many relation between `Department` and `ConferenceRoom` is called `DeptCRMapping`, if we have a given department ID equal to 7 for example, the conference rooms accessible to its employees would be the ones configured in the `DeptCRMapping` table **plus** the globally accessible conference rooms.

The SQL query I would write for such a requirement is the following :

```
SELECT CR.ID, CR.Name
 FROM ConferenceRoom CR
 LEFT JOIN DeptCRMapping DCRM ON CR.ID = DCRM.IDConferenceRoom
 WHERE DCRM.IdDepartment = 7
 OR    CR.IsAccessibleGlobally = 1
```

Here are my POCO Classes :

```
public class Department
{
    public long Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<ConferenceRoom> ConferenceRooms { get; set; }
}

public class ConferenceRoom
{
    public long Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

I can't figure out the Linq-To-Entities query I should write to get the SQL query mentioned above. Here's what I've tried so far :

```
var left = ctx.ConferenceRooms;
var right = ctx.ConferenceRooms.Where(v => v.Departments.Any(d => d.Id == 7));
var query = from l in left
            from r in right
            where l.Id == r.Id || l.AccesGlobal
            select l;
```

The generated sql is :

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Nom] AS [Nom], 
    [Extent1].[AccesGlobal] AS [AccesGlobal]
    FROM  [dbo].[Verbalisateur] AS [Extent1]
    CROSS JOIN [dbo].[Verbalisateur] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[VerbalisateursJuridiction] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[ID] = [Extent3].[IdVerbalisateur]) AND (5 = [Extent3].[IdJuridiction])
    )) AND ([Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[ID] OR [Extent1].[AccesGlobal] = 1)
```

Any ideas of what i can do to get a query similar to the one I want. On another note, would you guys recommend using native SQL when using an ORM, at least for querying results. Thank you.

---

#### EDIT

Well, After failing to find a way to execute native SQL Query with EF 6, I Just went with :

```
ctx.ConferenceRooms.Where(cf => cf.IsAccessibleGlobally || cf.Departments.Any(d => d.Id == 7))
```

Althought the generated query isn't what I was hoping for, at least the code is readable.

Answer (score 1):

Its often when there is a join involved especially when you are doing it often it should be a view. This should speed up the query time and it will explicitly define a way of looking at your data.  I would keep your native SQL in your database as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I don't have any way to test it, but since your query is equivalent to the following (performance should be similar and, in my opinion, easier to understand for newcomers):

```
SELECT 
    CR.ID, CR.Name
FROM ConferenceRoom CR
WHERE 
    CR.IsAccessibleGlobally = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    CR.ID, CR.Name
FROM DeptCRMapping DCRM
INNER JOIN ConferenceRoom CR ON DCRM.IDConferenceRoom = CR.ID
WHERE 
    DCRM.IdDepartment = 7
    and CR.IsAccessibleGlobally = 0
```

You can try the following LINQ query (currently I can't test the generated SQL) that should give a similar query to the above:

```
var query =
    ctx.ConferenceRoom
        .Where(cr => cr.IsAccessibleGlobally == 1)
        .Select(cr => new { cr.ID, cr.Name })
        .Concat(
            ctx.Department
                .Where(d => d.Id == 7)
                .Select(d => 
                    d.ConferenceRooms
                    .Where(cr => cr.IsAccessibleGlobally == 0)
                    .Select(cr => new { cr.ID, cr.Name }))
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
var rooms = ctx.ConferenceRooms
               .Where(v => v.Departments.Any(d => d.Id == 7)
                        || v.AccesGlobal);
```